# How to rerun/refresh a div that contains a php script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and ajax.

My code essentially calls a `ping.php` script that the fsockopen with an if else statement that prints server up or down creating a dashboard of my servers/services
currently when i load the page it calls prints the result either server up or down in the tile. 
(using merto.js to learn and play with)

The issue I'm having is that I'm struggling with is that I want to refresh the div say every 3 seconds to refresh the php script

```
<div class="tiles red">
    <div class="live-tile" id="tile1">        
        <div><?php include"ping1.php";  ?></div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using the following but I must be doing something wrong.

```
function startActivityRefresh() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $("tile1").load('ping1.php');
    }, seconds*1)
```

Even though my experimentation is fairly simplistic I do not want to simply refresh the entire page

I have tested it by creating an available port on 4220 than killing it off a few seconds later.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to check if the server is up or down, I would recommend using just a small [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (shorthand used in demo [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)) call instead of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Here is what my `status.php` script looks like.

```
<?php

// ping google.
$server = fsockopen('173.194.46.64', '80'); 

if ($server) { 
    echo 'Online';
    fclose($server); 
} else 
    echo 'Offline';
```

I ping google. Change the ip to your server.

Here is what my ajax call looks like

```
function checkServerStatus() {
    var status = $('#tile1');   // your element

    if (window.console && window.console.log)
        console.log('Checking server for status.');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });

    $.get('status.php')
    .done(function (e) {
        // let's suppose "e" will return "Online" or "Offline"

        // remove online and offline classes
        status.removeClass('status-offline status-online');

        // add a class if offline or online.
        switch (e) {
            case 'Online':
                status.addClass('status-online');
                break;
            case 'Offline':
                status.addClass('status-offline');
                break;
        }

        // set status text
        status.text(e);

        // check status every 5 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            checkServerStatus();
        }, 5000);
    })
    .fail(function (e) {
        if (window.console && window.console.log) console.log(e);
    });
}

// let's rock!
checkServerStatus();
```

Comment: Thanks Dennis it works i can see the status.php being called again however after the refresh my div vanishes checking firebug i notice prior to the refresh `<div id="tile1" class="live-tile">`
`<div>Online </div>` after `<div id="tile1" class="live-tile status-online">Online</div>`
`</div>`

Comment: I have sorted out the class issue how can i get that div tag to generate correctly after the refresh?

Comment: ok i have sorted out the issue of the div tag but the server status is not changing from online to offline when the service is stopped

Comment: @cmos99 If you're using the php script from above, it will only check for server status. It will not check for services. I'd suggest using your script if you  have it checking for services. The one provided was only to show you a test of server availability.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the id in `<div class="live-tile" id="tile1">`

and calling through `$("tile1")` which is wrong to get the element by id you need `#` and to get element by class you need `.`

```
$("#tile1").load('ping1.php')
```

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) needs the url *A string containing the URL to which the request is sent* `$("#tile1").load(' your url to ping1.php')`

Comment: Thank you for your advice I made the changes `$("#tile1").load('/ping1.php')`but it does not seemed to have helped